# How to randomly remove a percentage of items from a list

Tags: python, list

I have two lists of equal length, one is a data series the other is simply a time series. They represent simulated values measured over time.

I want to create a function that removes a set percentage or fraction from both lists but at random. I.e. if my fraction is 0.2, I want to randomly remove 20% of the items from both lists, but they have to be the same items (same index in each list) removed.

For example, let n = 0.2 (20% to be deleted)

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
b = [0,1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81]
```

After the randomly removed 20%, they become

```
a_new = [0,1,3,4,5,6,8,9]
b_new = [0,1,9,16,25,36,64,81]
```

The relationship isn't as straightforward as the example, so I can't just perform this action on one list and then work out the second; they already exist as two lists. And they have to remain in the original order.

Thanks!

Comment: Simplest answer: remove the first or last x% of the list

Comment: Hi, I'd like it to be a random sample, not just a chunk missing off the end/beginning. Thanks

Comment: even removing first or last doesn't mean that indexes would be same from both the lists

Comment: Probably something along the lines of using `random.sample(pop, k)` to get a percentage of one list, and then using `index()` to figure out the index of which items you removed, and remove them from the other list.

Comment: It would - data series and time series

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
import random

a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
b = [0,1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81]

frac = 0.2  # how much of a/b do you want to exclude

# generate a list of indices to exclude. Turn in into a set for O(1) lookup time
inds = set(random.sample(list(range(len(a))), int(frac*len(a))))

# use `enumerate` to get list indices as well as elements. 
# Filter by index, but take only the elements
new_a = [n for i,n in enumerate(a) if i not in inds]
new_b = [n for i,n in enumerate(b) if i not in inds]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
b = [0,1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81]

frac = 0.2  # how much of a/b do you want to exclude

new_a, new_b = [], []

for i in range(len(a)):
    if random.random()>frac:  # with probability, add an element from `a` and `b` to the output
        new_a.append(a[i])
        new_b.append(b[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from random import randint as r

a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
b = [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]

percentage = 0.3

g = (r(0, len(a)-1) for _ in xrange(int(len(a) * (1-percentage))))

c, d = [], []
for i in g:
    c.append(a[i])
    d.append(b[i])

a, b = c, d

print a
print b
```

Answer (score 0):

If `a` and `b` are not very large, you could get away with using `zip`:

```
import random

a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
b = [0,1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81]

frac = 0.2  # how much of a/b do you want to exclude
ab = list(zip(a,b))  # a list of tuples where the first element is from `a` and the second is from `b`

new_ab = random.sample(ab, int(len(a)*(1-frac)))  # sample those tuples
new_a, new_b = zip(*new_ab)  # unzip the tuples to get `a` and `b` back
```

Note that this won't preserve the original order of `a` and `b`

Answer (score 0):

You can also operate the *zipped* a and b sequence, get the random sample of the indexes (to maintain the original order of items) and *unzip* into `a_new` and `b_new` again:

```
import random


a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
b = [0,1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81]

frac = 0.2

c = zip(a, b)  # c = list(zip(a, b)) on Python 3
indices = random.sample(range(len(c)), frac * len(c))
a_new, b_new = zip(*sorted(c[i] for i in sorted(indices)))

print(a_new)
print(b_new)
```

It can print:

```
(0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
(0, 4, 9, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = len(a)
n_drop = int(l * n)
n_keep = l - n_drop
ind = [1] * n_keep + [0] * n_drop
random.shuffle(ind)
new_a = [ e for e, i in zip(a, ind) if i ]
new_b = [ e for e, i in zip(b, ind) if i ]
```